# ASP.Net - Requested resource does not support http method 'GET'

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm writing a controller to get the Books with for certain authors with a specific rating. This is the code for the GET method :

```
public IQueryable<Book> GetBooks(string context)
{
   string rating = context.Split('?')[0];
   string[] authors = context.context.Split('?')[1].Split(',');
   return db.Books.Where(s => authors.Contains(s.AuthorName) && s.Rating == rating);
}
```

When I run the project and enter this URL :

```
http://localhost:65239/api/books/5?James,Tom
```

I get this error:
`<Error>
<Message>
The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'.
</Message>
</Error>`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: did you try [HttpGet] attribute ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
public JsonResult GetBooks(string context)
{
   string rating = context.Split('?')[0];
   string[] authors = context.context.Split('?')[1].Split(',');
   var books = db.Books.Where(s => authors.Contains(s.AuthorName) && s.Rating == rating);
   return Json(books, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was using the wrong URL format.

```
http://localhost:65239/api/books?context=5?James,Tom
```